# Is the beta of a BJT really the same as h_FE?

Tags: dc, bjt, gain

I am currently re-reading my old textbook *Microelectronics* by Millman and Grabel. Attached two pages. Here is a somewhat theoretical question on large signal parameters for the BJT.

Starting with Ebers-Moll equations (3-6) and (3-7) and assuming \$V_{CB} = 0\$ they easily derive the *common-base forward short circuit current gain* \$h_{FB}\$ which is defined as
$$
h_{FB} \equiv \left. -\frac{I_C}{I_E} \right|_{V_{CB} = 0}
$$
In \$h_{FB}\$ the **F** stands for FORWARD (normal use of transistor) and **B** for common-BASE. *Short-circuit* means that \$V_{CB} = 0\$, i.e. the collector is connected to common (base, as in this case) .

It is easy to see that \$h_{FB} = \alpha_F\$ as in equation (3-8). All good so far.

Then there is the *common-emitter forward short-circuit current gain*, \$h_{FE}\$ which is defined as
$$
h_{FE} \equiv \left. -\frac{I_C}{I_B} \right|_{V_{CE} = 0}
$$
i.e. the gain of collector current versus base current when the collector is grounded to the common emitter.

In (3-13) they define \$\beta_F = \frac{\alpha_F}{1-\alpha_F}\$ and then simply **claim** that \$h_{FE} = \beta_F\$. In other words, they claim that
$$
h_{FE} = \frac{\alpha_F}{1-\alpha_F}
$$

But when I do the math to derive \$h_{FE}\$ from Ebers-Moll, by using emitter as common and assuming \$V_{CE} = 0\$, I get
$$
h_{FE} = -\frac{\alpha_F - \frac{\alpha_F}{\alpha_R}}{1 - \alpha_F + (1 -\alpha_R) \frac{\alpha_F}{\alpha_R}} \neq \frac{\alpha_F}{1-\alpha_F}.
$$
What is right here? Can you derive \$h_{FE} = \beta_F\$?

Images from *Microelectronics* 2nd ed. by Jacob Millman & Arvin Grabel, McGraw-Hill 1987, pages 89 and 90.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You get \$h_{FE} \neq \frac{\alpha_F}{1-\alpha_F}\$. OK, not that, so what *do* you get? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: Going back as far as I've done (decades before my Millman from '79), \$\beta_{_\text{F}}=h_{_\text{FE}}\$. Note that the 'h' is from 'hybrid' and it refers to the early (1950's) hybrid-\$\pi\$ model, which was a later re-analysis developed from the earlier transport and injection versions published before it. (They are mathematically equivalent, though notation is different, but the hybrid-\$\pi\$ is used today as computer programs can linearize it with less effort and its modeling of the low-current variation of \$\beta\$ is also easier to handle.)

Comment: Here's a question: How do you design an experimental setup and then rigorously process the experimental results in order to find \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$ at \$V_{_\text{CE}}=0\:\text{V}\$? I'm curious what you imagine here.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: OK it is edited now.

Comment: @periblepsis: This is DC analysis, before the hybrid-pi (small signal) model is even introduced in the text. The h at this point refers to the regular hybrid two-port parameters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network#Hybrid_parameters_(h-parameters). Maybe Millman is confusing the large-signal beta and small-signal beta?

I don't know how I would set it up experimentally and I don't believe it is relevant since this is just model-based theory.

Comment: @periblepsis now that I think about it more, I believe the problem here is that Millman erroneously applies two-port concepts (h-parameters) to the DC model, which is non-linear. Two-ports are for linear networks only, such as the hybrid-pi.

Comment: Isn't beta = dic/dib?

Comment: @Antonio51 yes in a small-signal model. This is a large-signal (dc, no differentials) model.

Comment: @DrH.  Right. I just forget.

Comment: AFAIK, \$ \beta_0 \equiv h_{FE} = \frac{\alpha_F}{1-\alpha_F} \$. Just different names. All _static_ CE parameters to name correctly. If you do the math and don't find that result, you got something wrong or you missed some step. There're no approximations. See e.g. Sze if you want a more in-depth discussion, but it says the same.

Answer (score 1):

They are assuming the diode currents in Figure 3-11 are negligible when the diodes are reverse biased. \$h_{FE}\$ is defined with the collector-base junction reverse biased, therefore, \$I_{CD}\$ is negligibly small, which in turn means the \$\alpha_R\$ dependent current source is turned off.

Then \$I_C\$ = \$\alpha_F * I_{ED} = -\alpha_F * I_E\$ and the rest follows directly from that.

(Unsolicited side opinion: Millman's sign convention for the currents is awful.)